# In a ASP.Net Core Web service, how can I measure the time required to send the response over the network?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have web service end point (a get method) that returns a fairly large chunk of JSON data. I want to measure the amount of time required to transmit it over the network to the client. I don't want to include the time take to assemble the data or to serialize it to JSON, just the network transfer time. I don't think I can do this in the get method itself as it only returns the data, the transfer must occur some time after the request is complete. I am returning the response from the get method like this: `return Ok(content)` where content is .Net object so I am letting ASP.Net Core handle the serialization to JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [Result Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#result-filters). You can start the `StopWatch` in `OnResultExecuting` that is executed when the result of the action method is just about to be sent. Then stop the `StopWatch` in `OnResultExecuted` that is executed when the result is sent to the client. Then log the `ElapsedMilliseconds`

```
public class ResponseTimeAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger<ResponseTimeAttribute> _logger;
    private static Stopwatch _stopwatch;

    public ResponseTimeAttribute(ILogger<ResponseTimeAttribute> logger)
    {
        _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        _stopwatch.Start();
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        _logger.LogInformation($"Time took {_stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    }
}
```

In order to use the above filter, you need to use the TypeFilter attribute to resolve the dependencies via DI. In this case it is `ILogger<ResponseTimeAttribute>`. So on your action method, add like below:

```
[TypeFilter(typeof(ResponseTimeAttribute))]
public IActionResult YourAction()
{
    return Ok(content);
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: OP's asking _time to send_, not time to execute, so how does this measure the time required to transmit it over the network to the client?

Comment: `OnResultExecuting` and `OnResultExecuted` of the ResultFilterAttribute are executed when the action method is finished successfully and the result is just about to be sent to the client and has been already sent to the client respectively. So it's not the execution time of the whole action. As OP mentioned in the question *I don't want to include the time take to assemble the data or to serialize it to JSON*. The other option could be to use a `Middleware` but that would include the time to build and assemble the data and time spent by other middlewares